# update query dont work in vb.net

Tags: sql, database, select, sql-update

i want write update statement in code behind in vb.net.if ICCID is exists in tbl_ICCID then change status from 0 to 1 and Pic_Correct_ICCID.visible=true, if not exists , display "Not found".
i wrote this code but doesnt work and for all of ICCID that not exists in Tbl_ICCID Pic_Correct_ICCID.visible=true.
Please check my code and solve my problem.

```
in Cls_ICCID:

 Public Function Update_Status(ByVal ICCID_No As String, ByVal status As Integer) As String
        Try
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand
            Dim sql As String
            Dim sql2 As String
            Dim myConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection()
            myConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=TEHRANI\TEHRANI;Initial Catalog=GSMProduction;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1"
            **sql = "UPDATE Tbl_ICCID SET Status='" & status & "' Where ( ICCID = '" & ICCID_No & "' )"**
            myConnection.Open()
            cmd = New SqlCommand(sql, myConnection)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()
            Update_Status = ""
        Catch ex As SqlException
            Update_Status = "Not found"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Update_Status = "Not connect to server"
        End Try
    End Function

in Frm_Packing



Private Sub Txt_ICCID_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Txt_ICCID.TextChanged

        Pic_BP_Correct.Visible = False
        Pic_BP_Wrong.Visible = False

        Try
            If Txt_ICCID.Text.Length = Txt_ICCID.MaxLength Then
                lblError.Text = clsICCID.Update_Status(Txt_ICCID.Text.ToString(), 1)
                lblError.ForeColor = Color.Red
                stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream
                pic_barcode = Nothing
                cls.btnEncode(pic_barcode, Txt_ICCID.Text.Trim)
                pic_barcode.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
                f = New IO.FileStream("C:\test55.png", IO.FileMode.Create, IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)
                b = stream.ToArray
                f.Write(b, 0, b.Length)
                f.Close()
                Dim Val() = {stream.ToArray, Txt_ICCID.Text.Trim}
                ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(Val)
                crp_report.SetDataSource(ds.Tables(0))
                frm_crp.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crp_report
                If lblError.Text = "" Then
                    Pic_BP_Correct.Visible = True
                    GBDoubleCheck.Visible = True
                    Txt_LabelBarcode.Focus()
                Else
                    Pic_BP_Wrong.Visible = True
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Pic_BP_Wrong.Visible = True
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't manually insert your parameters into the string.  Use prepared queries instead.

Comment: what? i don't underestant your mean

Comment: You should have the database driver parse the parameters instead of manually passing them into the string.  Good example here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.prepare.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Most probably due to sending status column value as string instead of int. You should remove those single-quotes. Also, this is really really bad practice to concat queries like that. Use CommandBuilders kind of thing or Typed DataSets for saving yourself against SQL injections.

Comment: thank you for answer.please change my code....i don't how do..just i update value if exits!!!

Comment: Oh my. Following is the correct query:
sql = "UPDATE Tbl_ICCID SET Status=" & status & " WHERE (ICCID = '" & ICCID_No & "')"

Comment: how do i underestand that is iccid in database or no? because for every value , doesn't display Not found

Comment: i want is input iccid is not exists then display not found

Comment: SO is not the place for this kind of training. You should better take a course in Data Access in .NET.